# Find reference about expansion of gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, digamma-function

If there are any reference about the expansion of $$\Gamma\left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right),$$ where $p,q$ are integers with $1\leq p\leq q$?

Comment: Expansion around what ?

Comment: Such as the expansion of $\Gamma(1-x)$. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Is it for $0<x<1$ ?

Comment: Yes.@ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 1):

Around $x=0$,
$$\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ \psi ^{(n-1)}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)}{q^n\,n!}\,x^n$$
Around $x=p$,
$$\log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right)\right)=-\log \left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right)-\gamma  \,\left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\zeta(n)}n \left(\frac{p-x}{q}\right)^n$$